# Validate JWT token before request

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I'm writing an API that must verify if JWS has a valid signature and it's not expired - my project has a few routes and only a single route is protected.

I have create a filter:

```
@Component
class JWTFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        // code to validate JWT
        chain.doFilter(req, resp)
    }

}
```

And the SecConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecConfig(val authRequestFilter: AuthRequestFilter) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cash")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        http.addFilterBefore(authRequestFilter, <WhatShouldIPutHere.class>)
    }
}
```

I have created the `SecConfig` class to centralize all configuration and my API doesn't have any kind of login, I just receive the JWS Token and I need to ensure that is valid.

What is the correct implementation to be used in `<WhatShouldIPutHere.class>`?

edit:

It works but what's the point of use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` if I dont have Username/Pw authentication in my application?

```
http.addFilterBefore(authRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
```

edit 2:

Why is it validating **every** request? I just want to validate `/cash`

Answer (score 0):

> It works but what's the point of use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter if I dont have Username/Pw authentication in my application?

It tells spring where in the filter chain you want to place your JWT filter. See [filter ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters). More specifically, using `addFilterBefore` like that will put your filter just before the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

> Why is it validating every request? I just want to validate /cash

Because you have not configured any specific paths in this line:

```
http.addFilterBefore(authRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
```

Use `http.antMatchers("/cash").addFilterBefore...`

Answer (score -1):

You must use:

```
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
```

Comment: It crashed the application: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`

Comment: Also, my filter already extends `OncePerRequestFilter`

Comment: Try whit: OncePerRequestFilter::class.java

Comment: Throws an exception `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`